# Powershell button event to run a script

Tags: powershell

i have to make a graphic interface with powershell to display a list of PCs in a domain but i don't know how to set the script in the event button. The script is p1_compare.ps1. Actually the lists are in .csv files because i have no idea how to get them to display and set it in the interface

Comment: Lots of tutorials are available, for example using WinForms : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx or WPF : https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/

Comment: Yes but it doesn't help me to understand everything i need

Comment: In the first link about WinForms : `$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})` your script has to be placed between `$OKButton.Add_Click({your script here})`

Comment: Like I said before, search "powershell winforms" in Google and there are many tutorials with what you need to know. This is not difficult to understand if you take some time to search about it.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f09954c41e85460787237e69fb7cc7e

when i run the script the listview doesn't display the list of PCs and it tells me files are not found but they are all in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

I have done in another way to get result when pressing a command button 
for example:

```
$Button.Add_Click({
      Get-DiskInfo | Out-GridView
})
```